# Sequelize raw include/join

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to be able to do the following simple SQL query using Sequelize:

```sql
     SELECT * FROM one 
     JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, two_id FROM two GROUP BY two_id) AS table_two 
     ON one.two_id = two.two_id
```

I can't seem to find anything about raw include, or raw model

For performance reason, I don't want subselect in the main query (which I know sequelize already works well with) aka:

```sql
    SELECT * FROM one, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM two WHERE one.two_id = two.two_id) AS count
```

Regarding the following sequelize code (models One and Two exists)

```js
    models.One.findAll({
        include: [
          models: model.Two
          // what to add here in order to get the example SQL
        ]
      })
```

Comment: Sequelize can't use `include` in raw queries

Comment: Really sad from the most used ORM...Would you have another idea for my use case using Sequelize ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I found a somewhat hacky workaround:

You can use **fn** inside selections to use any SQL word (like **JOIN**), resulting in something like this for my use case:

```js
models.One.findAll({
  attributes: [
    fn('JOIN', literal('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM two WHERE one.two_id = two.two_id')),
  ],
});
```

Note you can do that only on the last attribute (else it's a misplaced joint)